# sklearn specifying number of clusters

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hierarchical-clustering, sklearn-pandas

For the clustering algorithms in sklearn, is there a way to specify how many clusters you want the algorithm to find (instead of the algorithm finding its own number of clusters)? From my inputted data, I'm hoping for 2 clusters instead of the 3 it outputs for me.

If it helps, I'm using the MeanShift algorithm (but my question applies to all of them). Also, most tutorials seem to use make_blobs, but I'm using pandas's read_csv to upload my data instead if that changes anything.

This is the beginning part of my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header = 0)
original_headers = list(df.columns.values)
df = df._get_numeric_data()
data = df.values
ms = MeanShift()
ms.fit(data)
labels = ms.labels_
cluster_centers = ms.cluster_centers_
n_clusters_ = len(np.unique(labels))
print("Number of estimated clusters:", n_clusters_)
```

Comment: No, you cannot set the number of clusters in `MeasShift`. You can try setting `bandwidth` param but that still may not get 2 clusters. If you can use other algorithms, [then check others here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#classes), most of which have a parameter `n_clusters` which you can set to get those many clusters.

Comment: @VivekKumar I suggest posting this as an answer - it does, after all, answer the question

Comment: @desertnaut I am hesistant to post this as an answer in its current form because I do not how to configure the params in `MeanShift` to get 2 clusters as the OP wanted. So I suggested to use other algos. Will do so once OP replies to this and is satisfied.

Comment: @VivekKumar if the other algorithms do split my data into the correct clusters (which I would assume it does), then by all means it answers my question :)

Comment: KMeans works well!

Comment: "correct clusters" is an ill-defined term; see the useful exposition here: [How to understand the drawbacks of K-means](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133656/how-to-understand-the-drawbacks-of-k-means)

Answer (score 0):

As some users said above, it is not possible set the number of clusters wanted in `MeanShift` algorithm.

When we talk about clustering, there are a lot of models to be employed depending on your problem. Density based models, like `MeanShift` and `DBSCAN`, try to find areas of higher density than the remainder of the data set. So, the number of clusters will be defined by the data itself.

On the other hand, for example, centroid based methods like `K-Means`, starts its iterations based on the number of centroids passed as parameter.

The following link shows a lot of clustering algorithms of `sklearn`. Try to figure out which one suits best in your problem.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_comparison.html

References:

https://towardsdatascience.com/the-5-clustering-algorithms-data-scientists-need-to-know-a36d136ef68

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis